# net_io_connectionclosed al enviar correo

Tags: c#

Tengo que enviar  corrreos por una cuenta corporativa pero tengo el siguiente  error

```
No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: net_io_connectionclosed.
```

He tratado de utilizar todos lo puertos  pero igual sige saliendo el error.
Según la empresa el correo notificaciones tiene permitido el host smtp-relay

```
public bool enviarMensaje()
{
    try
    {

        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Host = "smtp-relay.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("notificaciones@prueba.com", "notificaciones");
            
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("notificaciones@prueba.com");
            //Logger.error(this.ToString(), correo.correoMostrar);
            string[] mal = "prueba1@gmail.com".Split(';');
            if (mal.Count() > 0 || mal != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in mal)
                {
                    if (item != "")
                    {
                        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(item));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("prueba1@gmail.com"));
            }
            
            mail.Subject = "Prueba";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = "<p>Hola</p>";
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            client.Send(mail);
            mail.Dispose();
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Espero que esas credenciales que colocaste ahí **no sean de verdad**.... en todo caso, la cuenta debe estar configurada para que permita conexiones inseguras para permitir conexiones SMTP... por lo menos cuando yo voy a usar el SMTP de google usando mi cuenta personal me toca ir a la configuración de seguridad de mi cuenta y permito conexiones inseguras... luego lo vuelvo a colocar para no permitirlas, una vez que hice el envío de lo que necesito.

Comment: Hola, si claro no son esas las credenciales  y tiene activado  aplicaciones inseguras pero igual tengo el error

Comment: Edita el código fuente de la pregunta _ya_ y pon otra cosa.... _y_ modifica la clave de ese usuario _ya_. Esa información no se debe compartir aquí.

Comment: Para el smtp si te conectas a un gmail, mas bien seria con smtp.gmail.com